# Word for when something inappropriate or surprising is said or proclaimed in a jarring and nonchalant manner

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

An example is if I was speaking to someone about baseball or something similarly innocent and nonchalantly said "That reminds me of my mother. She was killed in a car accident two years ago." The person I'm addressing is obviously taken aback by the statement and shocked by the statement, while I, on the other hand, am behaving normally as if I hadn't said anything out of line.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 1):

> . . . The person I'm addressing is obviously taken aback by the
>   **bombshell**, while I, on the other hand, am behaving normally as if I hadn't said anything out of line.

**bomb(shell)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bombshell)

> n. a stunning piece of news that is dropped without warning.

**drop a bombshell (brick)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bombshell)

> To reveal something that is very surprising or unexpected.

Depending on the context and the needs of proper grammar, either idiom could be used.

Answer (score 0):

The action could be described as an incongruity and the person as **incongruous** though usually applied to objects rather than applied to people.

Not in harmony or keeping with the surroundings or other aspects of something.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incongruous

There are many formal and less formal terms used for such a reply

anomalous, bizarre, inscrutable, kitsch, kooky, left-field, outlandish...

and almost monosyllabic

**[inapt](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inapt)** (discordant) can be used for a remark that's *not suitable or appropriate in the circumstances.*

Comment: While this does seem to fit the context, I don't think this is the word I am looking for. I remember reading this word somewhere and looking up the definition. I can recall it being a shorter word, possibly even monosyllabic.

Comment: *gaffe* is monosyllabic.

Answer (score 0):

**"irreverence"** comes to mind, and the person comes across as **"irreverent"**.

> **irreverence**
>
> - "a lack of respect for people or things that are generally taken seriously"  [**The Oxdord Dictionary of Difficult Words**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=%22a+lack+of+respect+for+people+or+things+that+are+generally+taken+seriously%22&source=bl&ots=d2UWjSjbHS&sig=Pt9F36oU0lHta8G4IZwF9tq6-HA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihovfc-ZPfAhVTl5AKHfTwDtkQ6AEwBHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20lack%20of%20respect%20for%20people%20or%20things%20that%20are%20generally%20taken%20seriously%22&f=false)
> - "lack of reverence or due respect"  [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/irreverence)
> - "lack of reverence; disrespect, an act or statement showing this" [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/irreverence)
>
> **irreverent** - "having or showing a lack of respect for someone or something that is usually treated with respect : treating someone or something in a way that is not serious or respectful"  [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irreverent)

Answer (score 0):

> [***infelicity***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/infelicity) - something, esp a remark or expression, that is inapt or inappropriate

Sort of like *faux-pas* or *gaffe* but with less requirement for someone being mortified.